# What are some cool Javadoc doclet/templates?

Tags: java, templates, javadoc, xdoclet, doclet

I really don't like the way the default Javadocs look. I like the look of [this one](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/packages.html) better. What are some other templates/doclets I can use for generating better JavaDoc pages?

Comment: 'Better looking' is in the eye of the beholder. This really isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Err, I think everyone would agree that the Javadoc link I posted in the question is better than the default one. And even if we take out the "look" the second one is more functional (has a search bar and a version drop down). So why is my question invalid? I am looking for other such good doclets given that I ran into my example by accident. Where shall I ask this question then??

Comment: The one you are linking to is produced by [Doclava](http://code.google.com/p/doclava/). I'm not totally sure that is is really more functional - it is missing the list of all classes, for example. For "better looking", you can simply use another stylesheet with the standard doclet.

Comment: Unrelated: Why the hell do they put the (generated) javadocs into the SVN repository?